# How to use React ThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs

I have follwed a few different tutorials and just can't seem to get this working. The styles aren't applied. Here is App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// Material UI Components
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import FormGroup from '@mui/material/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";


// Custom Components
import Header from "./components/header/header.component.js";

// import theme
import theme from "./theme.js";

function App() {

  return  (
    <>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Container maxWidth="md" >
        <Grid container  > 
          <Grid container justifyContent="center">
            <Grid item  xs={6} md={6} >
              <Header titleText="Title" />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container justifyContent="center">
            <Grid item  xs={6} md={6} >
              <FormGroup>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Hello</Button>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">World</Button>
              </FormGroup>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and theme.js:

```
import { createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { amber, deepPurple, lightGreen } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: lightGreen[500]
        },
        secondary: {
            main: amber[500],
            contrastText: lightGreen[900]
        }
    }
  });

  export default theme;
```

I have spent hours on this... it's seems like it should be so easy. Any ideas? It wants me to type more text before I can post my question. Annoying user experiences are really annoying.

Comment: Is the rest of the app working or is the build broken?  Depending on how you are _running_ this it may be serving you the last thing that actually _built_, not the current code.  For example, the import for `ThemeProvider` in [the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#themeprovider) is `@mui/material/styles` (not, as you have it, `@material-ui/styles`)

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank you!